# Each tag in template not working if I use HTTP get

Tags: json, http, templates, meteor

I'm trying to to processing JSON from HTTP, but it's not working.

My endpoint bring me this JSON:

```
[  
   {  
      "data":"1992-04-27 00:00:00",
      "0":"1992-04-27 00:00:00",
      "numeroProntuario":"PAR 08 1377 051",
      "1":"PAR 08 1377 051",
      "nome":"ABDO AZIZ NADER ",
      "2":"ABDO AZIZ NADER ",
      "nascimento":"1933-08-26 00:00:00",
      "3":"1933-08-26 00:00:00",
      "sexo":"M",
      "4":"M",
      "estado_civil":"CASADO",
      "5":"CASADO",
      "filhos":"0",
      "6":"0",
      "local_nascimento":"BEIRUT ",
      "7":"BEIRUT ",
      "rg":"",
      "8":"",
      "cpf":"",
      "9":"",
      "enviado_por":"",
      "10":"",
      "endereco_res":"RUA ANT\u00d4NIO ANDRADE REBELO, 912",
      "11":"RUA ANT\u00d4NIO ANDRADE REBELO, 912",
      "bairro_res":"MORUMBI ",
      "12":"MORUMBI ",
      "cidade_res":"S\u00c3O PAULO",
      "13":"S\u00c3O PAULO",
      "estado_res":"SP",
      "14":"SP",
      "cep_res":"05692000",
      "15":"05692000",
      "fone_res":"",
      "16":"",
      "celular":"",
      "17":"",
      "profissao":"INDUSTRIAL ",
      "18":"INDUSTRIAL ",
      "cargo":"DIRETOR ",
      "19":"DIRETOR ",
      "atividade":"",
      "20":"",
      "empresa":"INTEXTIL ALIL NADER ",
      "21":"INTEXTIL ALIL NADER ",
      "endereco_com":"RUA CONSELHEIRO COTEGIPE, 294",
      "22":"RUA CONSELHEIRO COTEGIPE, 294",
      "cidade_com":"S\u00c3O PAULO",
      "23":"S\u00c3O PAULO",
      "estado_com":"SP",
      "24":"SP",
      "cep_com":"03058000",
      "25":"03058000",
      "fone_com":"",
      "26":"",
      "motivo":"STRESS",
      "27":"STRESS",
      "email":"",
      "28":"",
      "numeroCartao":"",
      "29":"",
      "cod_convenio":"PAR",
      "30":"PAR",
      "codigo_convenio_plano":"116",
      "31":"116",
      "codigo_paciente":"2290",
      "32":"2290"
   }
]
```

And my script is:

```
Template.listarCampanhas.helpers ({
  paciente : function(){
    try {
      HTTP.get("http://localhost:90/medico/testeAccess.php",null,function( error, response ) {
        return response.data;
      });
    }
    catch(e){
      console.log( "Cannot get paciente data...", e );
    }   
  }
});
```

In my template I have:

```
<template name="listarCampanhas">
  <h3>Campanhas</h3>
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>numero Prontuario</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {{#each paciente}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{nome}}</td>
        <td>{{numeroProntuario}}</td>
      </tr>
      {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <hr>
</template>
```

Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Comment: Try using `JSON.parse` on that response.data or wherever your response is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return just response instead of `response.data` i.e.

```
HTTP.get("http://localhost:90/medico/testeAccess.php",null,function( error, response ) {
    return response;
  });
```

Since there isn't any `response.data` in the returned json.

I'm guessing what you really should do is check the code that returns the json, as it looks wrong like the way its showing.

Comment: not work, but if i put json response manually like this:  return [{"data":"1992-04-27 00:00:00",
     "numeroProntuario":"PAR 08 1377 051",
     "nome":"ABDO AZIZ NADER "
     
     },
     {"data":"1992-04-27 00:00:00",
     "numeroProntuario":"PAR 08 1377 051",
     "nome":"ABDO AZIZ NADER "
     
     },
     {"data":"1992-04-27 00:00:00",
     "numeroProntuario":"PAR 08 1377 051",
     "nome":"ABDO AZIZ NADER "
     
     },{"data":"1992-04-27 00:00:00",
     "numeroProntuario":"PAR 08 1377 051",
     "nome":"ABDO AZIZ NADER "
     
     }]; then work

Comment: That's what I said, your endpoint isn't returning the json in the structure that you need.

Comment: That's not the problem here. Using `HTTP.get` will always have a `data` key in the response. See https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning the response from the function correctly. Remember, this is an asynchronous API request that will return at a later time, so you'll need a way to reactively set the variable.

The simplest way to do this is to use reactive variables. If you don't have the package already, run

```
meteor add reactive-var
```

Then, make adjustments to your code like so:

```
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var'

Template.listarCampanhas.onCreated(function() {
  const apiResponse = new ReactiveVar() // initialize a new reactive var

  // this is when we request to the API
  try {
    // this will return later, but it'll set the reactive
    // variable `apiResponse` to whatever the result returns
    HTTP.get("http://localhost:90/medico/testeAccess.php", null, function(error, response) {
      // when returned, set the result to the reactive variable
      return apiResponse.set(response.data)
    })
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log( "Cannot get paciente data...", e );
  }

  this.data.apiResponse = apiResponse; // bind the reactive var to the template
});

Template.listarCampanhas.helpers ({
  paciente : function(){
    // helpers of a template is always reactively run,
    // i.e. everytime `apiResponse` changes this will get re-run

    return this.apiResponse.get() // return the api response that's set
  }
})
```

`reactive-var` is a core, must-understand concept that'll help you in building an app with Meteor. You can google resources across the Internet that covers this.

Here is one good read on the topic:

https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/reactive-dict-reactive-vars-and-session-variables